# Unlock samsung galaxy s2 too many pattern attempts and failed to login in gmail account then reset

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens

My samsung galaxy s2 is locked, after restart, I see following welcome screen only

[image]

Here was my fault :(

1. Exceed to many pattern attempts
2. Then system asked for associated google account and password. Lack of internet connection I was failed to  login.
3. Then restart the galaxy sII by thinking that I would have chance to give pattern one more
4. But no lack I see ' S(logo) Samsung Galaxy SII ' on screen. I can not nothing to forward

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Likely you will need to try a factory reset from Recovery mode.

Comment: Based on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szecTSVAWl8 I have following options 1. reboot system now 2. apply update from external storage 3. wipe data/factory reset 4. wipe wipe cache partition 5. apply update from cache 
I choose 3. wipe data/factory reset and yes -- clear all user data 
after reset I have same thing now luck :(

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Do you have a warranty?  You might want to send it in, if not you could try flashing the stock ROM with Odin.

Comment: I do not have warranty. have any side effect of flashing? **Edit:** I have tried 3. wipe data/factory reset + clear all user data again. NOW WORKS !!!!! thanks a lot Matthew Read

Comment: Great, glad to help.  Since we don't really know what happened here I'm going to go ahead and close this question.